# HAProxy - Need to add a URL parameter to ACL to differentiate between services with the same URL, but on different ports

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, configuration, haproxy, access-control-list

I have several services that run on different ports, each of which use the same URI paths.  For example:

```
New York Housing Service
127.0.0.1:8080/homes
127.0.0.1:8080/prices

Las Vegas Housing Service
127.0.0.1:8081/homes
127.0.0.1:8081/prices
```

This has been fine so far, but I now need to set up haproxy to load balance the services.  As such, I obviously need to be able to differentiate them for content switching.  What I imagine I would do is add a parameter to the path in the ACL to differentiate between the two backends, in this case by having a url parameter in the ACL, which would be followed by the actual path parameters for the application:

```
frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:5000  

  acl new-york path_reg -i /newyork.*
  use_backend nyc-server if new-york

  acl las-vegas path_reg -i /lasvegas.*
  use_backend lv-server if las-vegas

backend nyc-server
  server www.test.com 127.0.0.1:8080 maxconn 100

backend lv-server
  server www.test.com 127.0.0.1:8081 maxconn 100
```

In this setup, going to 127.0.0.1:5000/newyork/home will take me to 127.0.0.1:**8080**/home, while 127.0.0.1:5000/lasvegas/home takes me to 127.0.0.1:**8081**/home.  My attempts so far have simply returned a 404 error.  I've been been going through the documentation, but I did not see anything quite matching my use case, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I'm using haproxy 1.5.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend services are answering with HTTP 404 errors because your HAPROXY configuration is currently forwarding URL's path as they are. For example, a HTTP request for `http://127.0.0.1:5000/newyork/home/wtc.png` is being forwarded to `nyc-server` backend as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/newyork/home/wtc.png`.

```
$ wget -4O /dev/null http://localhost:5000/newyork/homes/wtc.png
--2020-02-01 13:00:09--  http://localhost:5000/newyork/homes/wtc.png
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 File not found
2020-02-01 13:00:09 ERROR 404: File not found.
```

```
$ python -m http.server 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2020 13:00:09] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2020 13:00:09] "GET /newyork/homes/wtc.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

---

HAproxy should be configured to translate URLs' paths by stripping the first path component while fetching resources from backends. I would suggest you to add a `reqrep`  directive into frontend's definition, which is meant to manipulate the first line of the HTTP request header and translate something like `GET /newyork/homes/wtc.png HTTP/1.1` into `GET /homes/wtc.png HTTP/1.1`.

```
frontend http
  reqrep ^([A-Z]+)\ /+[^/]+(/+.*)?$  \1\ \2
```

However, it won't work because HAproxy evaluates `reqrep` directives before `use-backend` ones, thus breaking backend evaluation:

```
$ wget -4O /dev/null http://localhost:5000/newyork/homes/wtc.png
--2020-02-01 13:54:55--  http://localhost:5000/newyork/homes/wtc.png
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2020-02-01 13:54:55 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

A second working approach is rewriting URL path in backend definitions. However, depending on the number of backends in service, writing `reqrep` directives and configuring each backend to perform URL rewrite are prone to error.

```
backend nyc-server
  server www.test.com 127.0.0.1:8080 maxconn 100
  reqrep ^([A-Z]+)\ /+[^/]+(/+.*)?$  \1\ \2

backend lv-server
  server www.test.com 127.0.0.1:8081 maxconn 100
  reqrep ^([A-Z]+)\ /+[^/]+(/+.*)?$  \1\ \2
```

```
$ wget -4O /dev/null http://localhost:5000/newyork/homes/wtc.png
--2020-02-01 14:02:29--  http://localhost:5000/newyork/homes/wtc.png
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 456892 (446K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null        100%[===============>] 446.18K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-02-01 14:02:29 (1.83 GB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [456892/456892]
```

```
$ python -m http.server 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2020 14:02:29] "GET /homes/wtc.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```